# data manipulation - R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, reshape2

I am struggling with data manipulation in R. My dataset consists of variables `type`(5 factors), `intensity`(3 factors), `damage`(continous). I want to calculate mean `damage`(demage1, demage2 and damage3 separately) with respect to `intensity` and `type`. *In onther words I want to summarize the average damage by type and intensity.* I have created this small reproducible example of my data:

```
type <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 5, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)

intensity <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 3, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)

damage1 <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 50, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
damage2 <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 200, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
damage3 <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 500, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)

dat <- cbind(type, intensity, damage1, damage2, damage3)
```

then to manipulate the data I have used the pipe operator `%>%` buy my commands seem not to work very well:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)

dat %>%
  filter(type == 1) %>%
  group_by(intensity, damage) %>%
  summarise(mean_damage = mean(Value))
```

I have read about multiple usefull functions here:

1. [efficient reshaping using data tables](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html)
2. [manipulating data tables](http://personal.colby.edu/personal/m/mgimond/RIntro/04_Manipulating_data_tables.html#combining-table-manipulation-functions-using)
3. [Do Faster Data Manipulation using These 7 R Packages](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/12/faster-data-manipulation-7-packages/)

But I wasnt able to make any progress here. My question are:

**What is wrong with my code?**

**Am I even going in the right direction here?**

**Is there some alternative how to do this?**

Comment: can you explain what you'd expect to see for one or two rows?

Comment: To start with, there is a pipe operator missing between the `group_by` and the `summarise` function. Moreover, why is there `damage1, damage2` and `damage3`? Why are there numbers in the column names but not in your code? And if you want the mean by type, why do you condition on `type == 1`?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: `dat %>% group_by(type, intensity) %>% summarize_all(mean)`.

Comment: To create a data.frame don't use `cbind()` and `as.data.frame()` but create it directly by `dat <- data.frame(type, intensity, damage1, damage2, damage3)`. Otherwise, it may happen that cbind() unexpectedly will change data types as it creates a matrix by default.